# Codeigniter Insert allow script and html tag but display in raw code when echo not run

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

I have implement chat box that allow user to type chat for asking some question support.

but I don't know how to insert and display chat back with html or some script but not run just display what they typed in box.
Sample Picture:

[image]

**SQL INSERT**

```
$sms = $this->input->post('sms' , TRUE);
$querynewsms = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_smschat(chatsms, user_id, sent_to, sent_datetime)VALUES('$sms', '$user_id', '0', '$now')");
```

**SQL SELLECT CHAT**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_smschat WHERE user_id='$user_id' OR sent_to='$user_id'");//Get All Chat by userID
```

**DISPLAY CHAT**

```
<p><div class="wrap">'.$row->chatsms.'</div></p>
```